# How can I show the Area?

Tags: java

I have a few codes here. I tried to solve the question in the How to program Java book. I summarized the question below:

> You are required to implement the following design as well as a `main()` method in another class to test your implementation:
>   Implement the hierarchy below where:
>
> - `MyShape` is an abstract class with an abstract `Draw` method,
> - `MyBoundedShape` is an abstract class with an abstract `GetArea` method,
> - `MyLine`, `MyOval`, `MyRectangle` are concrete classes
>
> In the `main()` method,
>
> - Ask the user to select 5 shapes and input their dimension
> - Draw selected shapes
> - Compute and show the area of selected shapes if they are a bounded shape

When I ran the code, it didn't show the area or the calculated area.

Here is those code:

`MyShape` class

```
public abstract class MyShape 
{
    public abstract void Draw();
}
```

`Myline` class

```
public class Myline extends MyShape 
{
    private int length;
    public Myline (int length)
    {
           length=0;
    }
    public void setlength( int length )
    {
           length = 0; 
    } 
    public int getlength()
    {
           return length;
    } 
    public void Draw()
    {
           System.out.printf("Drawing a line with the length",getlength());
    }
}
```

`Myextendedshape` class

```
public abstract class MyextendedShape extends MyShape 
{
    protected double area;
    public abstract double getArea();

}
```

`Myoval` class

```
public class Myoval extends MyextendedShape
{
    private double Line1;
    private double Line2;
    public void Draw() 
    {
        System.out.println("I am drawing  a Oval");
    }

     Myoval()
    {
        Line1= 0.0;
        Line2 = 0.0;        
    }

    Myoval(double Line1, double Line2){
        this.Line1 =Line1;
        this.Line2 = Line2;
    }
    public double getLine1()
    {
        return Line1;
    }

    public void setLine1(double Line1)
    {
        this.Line1 = Line1;
    }

    public double getLine2()
    {
        return Line2;
    }

    public void setLine2(double Line2)
    {
        this.Line2 = Line2;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea()
    {
        return calculateArea();
    }


    private double calculateArea()
    {
        return area = 3.14*Line1 * Line2;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "The Line number 1 of the oval is: " + Line1 + " and the Line number 2 is: " + Line2 + ", "+ "and the area is: " + getArea();
    }

}
```

`MyRectangle` class

```
public class MyRectangle extends MyextendedShape {
    private double length, width;

    public void Draw() 
    {
        System.out.println("I am drawing  a Rectangle");
    }

    MyRectangle()
    {
        length= 0.0;
        width = 0.0;        
    }

    MyRectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        this.length =length;
        this.width = width;
    }



    public double getLenght() 
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) 
    {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) 
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea()
    {
        return calculateArea();
    }


    private double calculateArea()
    {
        return area = width * length;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "The width of the rectangle is: " + width + " and the length is: " + length + ", "+ "and the area is: " + getArea();
    }

}
```

`Test`

```
public class test 
{
     public static void main(String [] args) 
     {

         MyShape s = new Myline(6);
         s.Draw();

         s =  new Myoval(4.0, 5.0);
         s.Draw();

         s = new MyRectangle(4.0,6.0);
         s.Draw();

        }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie here, but can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are only ever executing the `Draw()` method in main. If you look at your code, the only thing your `Draw()` method does is print to screen "`I am drawing a [shape]`"

If you want to also print out the area of each shape, you either have to call your 'getArea()' methods in main (as you did with 'Draw'), or make 'Draw' include functionality to output the area. I'll demonstrate the first method.

```
public class test 
{
     public static void main(String [] args) 
     {

         MyShape s = new Myline(6);
         s.Draw();

         s =  new Myoval(4.0, 5.0);
         s.Draw();
         //This calculates the area of s, and then prints it to screen.
         System.out.println(s.getArea());

         s = new MyRectangle(4.0,6.0);
         s.Draw();
         System.out.println(s.getArea());

        }
}
```

Note that nowhere in your code is there anything that attempts to actually *draw* a shape. I suggest you re-read part of the book if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The code that you gave me is getting Area method in MyShape, and MyShape is only had Draw method. Thanks for the answer but still having an error message.